# Gstreamer hangs while generating timelapse from JPEGs on Raspberry pi

Tags: gstreamer, raspberry-pi, video-processing, openmax

**Situation:**

I want to generate a timelapse on my Raspberry Pi 512mb, using the onboard  H.264 encoder.

Input: +300 JPEG files (2592 x 1944 pixels), example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NK8r.jpg

Output: h264 video file  (2592 x 1944 pixels)

GStreamer 1.0.8 + omxencoder (http://pastebin.com/u8T7mE18)

Raspberry Pi version: Jun 17 2013 20:45:38 version d380dde43fe729f043befb5cf775f99e54586cde (clean) (release)

Memory: gpu_mem_512=400

**Gstreamer pipeline:**

> sudo gst-launch-1.0 -v multifilesrc location=GOPR%04d.JPG
>   start-index=4711 stop-index=4750
>   caps="image/jpeg,framerate=(fraction)25/1" do-timestamp=true !
>   omxmjpegdec ! videorate ! video/x-raw,framerate=1/5 ! videoconvert  !
>   omxh264enc ! "video/x-h264,profile=high" ! h264parse ! queue
>   max-size-bytes=10000000 ! matroskamux ! filesink location=test.mkv
>   --gst-debug=4

**Problem:**
Gstreamer hangs and no output is generated.

--gst-debug=4:

> 0:00:01.027331700  2422  0x17824f0 INFO GST_EVENT
>   gstevent.c:709:gst_event_new_segment: creating segment event time
>   segment start=0:00:00.000000000, stop=99:99:99.999999999,
>   rate=1.000000, applied_rate=1.000000, flags=0x00,
>   time=0:00:00.000000000, base=0:00:00.000000000, position
>   0:00:00.000000000, duration 99:99:99.999999999
>
> 0:00:29.346875982  2422 0x17824f0 INFO                 basesrc
>   gstbasesrc.c:2619:gst_base_src_loop: pausing after
>   gst_base_src_get_range() = eos

--gst-debug=5:

> 0:01:16.089222125  2232   0x1fa8f0 DEBUG                basesrc
>   gstbasesrc.c:2773:gst_base_src_loop: pausing task,
>   reason eos
>
> 0:01:16.095962979  2232   0x1fa8f0 DEBUG               GST_PADS
>   gstpad.c:5251:gst_pad_pause_task: pause task
>
> 0:01:16.107724723  2232   0x1fa8f0 DEBUG                   task
>   gsttask.c:662:gst_task_set_state: Changing task
>   0x2180a8 to state 2
>
> 0:01:16.435800597  2232   0x1fa8f0 DEBUG              GST_EVENT
>   gstevent.c:300:gst_event_new_custom: creating new event 0x129f80 eos
>   28174
>
> 0:01:16.436191588  2232   0x1fa8f0 DEBUG               GST_PADS
>   gstpad.c:4628:gst_pad_push_event: event eos updated
>
> 0:01:16.436414584  2232   0x1fa8f0 DEBUG               GST_PADS
>   gstpad.c:3333:check_sticky: pushing all sticky
>   events
>
> 0:01:16.436620579  2232   0x1fa8f0 DEBUG               GST_PADS
>   gstpad.c:3282:push_sticky: event stream-start was
>   already received
>
> 0:01:16.436816575  2232   0x1fa8f0 DEBUG               GST_PADS
>   gstpad.c:3282:push_sticky: event caps was already
>   received
>
> 0:01:16.437001571  2232   0x1fa8f0 DEBUG               GST_PADS
>   gstpad.c:3282:push_sticky: event segment was
>   already received
>
> 0:01:16.440457495  2232   0x1fa8f0 DEBUG              GST_EVENT
>   gstpad.c:4771:gst_pad_send_event_unchecked:
>   have event type eos event at time 99:99:99.999999999: (NULL)
>
> 0:01:16.449986289  2232   0x1fa8f0 DEBUG           videodecoder
>   gstvideodecoder.c:1144:gst_video_decoder_sink_event:
>   received event 28174, eos
>
> 0:01:16.462165024  2232   0x1fa8f0 DEBUG            omxvideodec
>   gstomxvideodec.c:2489:gst_omx_video_dec_drain:
>   Draining component
>
> 0:01:16.463930986  2232   0x1fa8f0 DEBUG                    omx
>   gstomx.c:1223:gst_omx_port_acquire_buffer:
>   Acquiring video_decode buffer from port 130
>
> 0:01:16.465537951  2232   0x1fa8f0 DEBUG                    omx
>   gstomx.c:1334:gst_omx_port_acquire_buffer:
>   video_decode port 130 has pending buffers
>
> 0:01:16.466576928  2232   0x1fa8f0 DEBUG                    omx
>   gstomx.c:1353:gst_omx_port_acquire_buffer:
>   Acquired buffer 0x21f938 (0xb2068550) from video_decode port 130: 0
>
> 0:01:16.468237892  2232   0x1fa8f0 DEBUG                    omx
>   gstomx.c:1375:gst_omx_port_release_buffer:
>   Releasing buffer 0x21f938 (0xb2068550) to video_decode port 130
>
> 0:01:16.470360846  2232   0x1fa8f0 DEBUG                    omx
>   gstomx.c:1420:gst_omx_port_release_buffer:
>   Released buffer 0x21f938 to video_decode port 130: None (0x00000000)
>
> 0:01:16.472046809  2232   0x1fa8f0 DEBUG            omxvideodec
>   gstomxvideodec.c:2544:gst_omx_video_dec_drain:
>   Waiting until component is drained

Full console dump: https://mega.co.nz/#!eI1ASBSY!R4mnuGqRH7M8dT4q6j03mBKsQ1A-7oCXU4stu50LnOw

**Question:**

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. Is there another or more efficient way to create high res timelapses from JPEGs on a raspberry pi?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry about the necro, but I think this is trying to use the `Raspberry Pi HW H264` encoder at a higher resolution than it is capable of. It can manage just over `1080p30`, and has a maximum line length of `2048` pixels, so your source images are too large.

You could try `MJPEG` which does not have the same limitation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a Pi to test on right now, but I'd suspect one possible issue is that you have two OMX elements in the same process.  GStreamer is just wrapping OMX and IIRC the OMX API doesn't really want you running two things at once, particularly in the same process...

I'd try it with a jpegdec instead of omxmjpegdec, with a pipeline more along these lines:

gst-launch-1.0 multifilesrc location="GOPR%04d.JPG "start-index=4711 stop-index=4750 ! image/jpeg,framerate=1/5 ! jpegdec ! videoconvert ! omxh264enc ! h264parse ! matroskamux ! filesink location=test.mkv

I don't think there is any point to using queue elements on the Pi either.